# Doctrine inserts only empty values no matter what I set the model values to

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Here is how I create a tournament and save it:

```
  $tournament =  new Entities\Tournament();
  $tournament->setTitle("this is strange");
  var_dump($tournament->getTitle());
  $this->em->persist($tournament);
  $this->em->flush();
```

This is the tournament class:

```
<?php
namespace Entities;/** * @Entity @Table(name="jos_gsa_tournament") */
use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
class Tournament { /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
  protected $id;//** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
  protected $title;//** @Column(type="string",length=255) */

  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }
  public function setId($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }
  public function getTitle() {
    return $this->title;
  }
  public function setTitle($title) {
    $this->title = $title;
  }
}
?>
```

After running the above mentioned code I have a tournament entry in the database with an empty string for title. Even though the var_dump dumps "this is strange".

Comment: Isn't the `@Entity` annotation meant to go just above the `class` declaration? Same for the `@Column` annotations

Comment: @Phil yes, thank you. Botched up a copy paste somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your annotation syntax is incorrectly placed. It should look like this...

```
namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="jos_gsa_tournament")
 */
class Tournament {
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string",length=255) */
    protected $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Messed up my annotations, should be:

```
<?php
namespace Entities;
use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/** * @Entity @Table(name="jos_gsa_tournament") */
class Tournament { 
  /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue */
  protected $id;
  /** @Column(type="string",length=255) */
  protected $title;
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question revision?

Comment: @Phil You're free to add your comment as an answer and I'll except it. Since there were no errors I didn't look at the obvious place. As you were writing the comment I just found what's wrong by reading my question again.

Comment: I'd still put the `@Entity` and `@Table` comment block right above the class